# Vector subscript out of range error - C++ Vectors & OpenCV4

Tags: c++, opencv

I am writing a program that would merge images with SURF,but an unresolved bug has been encountered,about Vector out of range.(i cannot speak english very well,im sorry about that);

My programe

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
Mat image01, image02;
image01 = imread("D:/work/Temp/拼接A1.jpg");
image02 = imread("D:/work/Temp/拼接A2.jpg");

Ptr<xfeatures2d::SURF> surf = xfeatures2d::SURF::create(1000);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoint01, keypoint02;
Mat dsp01, dsp02;
surf->detect(image01, keypoint01);
surf->detect(image02, keypoint02);
surf->compute(image01, keypoint01, dsp01);
surf->compute(image02, keypoint02, dsp02);


vector<DMatch> dmatch;
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create("FlannBased");
matcher -> match(dsp01, dsp02, dmatch);

double maxDist = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dsp01.rows; i++) {
    double dist = dmatch[i].distance;
    if (dist > maxDist)
        maxDist = dist;
}

vector<DMatch> good_matches;

for (int k = 0; k < dsp01.rows; k++)
{
    if (dmatch[k].distance < 0.4*maxDist) {
        good_matches.push_back(dmatch[k]);
    }
}


Mat imageout;
drawMatches(image01, keypoint01, image02, keypoint02, good_matches, imageout);
imshow("11", imageout);

vector<Point2f> imagePoint2;
vector<Point2f> imagePoint1;
imagePoint1.resize(good_matches.size());
imagePoint2.resize(good_matches.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++) {
    if (good_matches.empty())
    {
        cout << "no good matches" << endl;
        break;
    }
        imagePoint2.push_back(keypoint02[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        imagePoint1.push_back(keypoint01[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
}
```

and the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5kSi.png)

Comment: Please share error snippet instead of its picture

Comment: vector<Point2f> imagePoint2;
 vector<Point2f> imagePoint1;
 imagePoint1.resize(good_matches.size());
 imagePoint2.resize(good_matches.size());
 for (size_t i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++) {
  if (good_matches.empty())
  {
   cout << "no good matches" << endl;
   break;
  }
   imagePoint2.push_back(keypoint02[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
   imagePoint1.push_back(keypoint01[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
 }

Comment: Edit your post not comment. Also underline the which line causing error? Is that `.push_back` line?

Comment: yes,i think the problem is'imagePoint2.push_back(keypoint02[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
   imagePoint1.push_back(keypoint01[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);',I am not proficient in using this website,Thank you for your patience

Comment: and...How to add code to reply?qaq

Comment: When you deleted `imagePoint2.push_back...` and `imagePoint1.push_back...` lines: do you still get the eerors?

Comment: no,when i delete them , the error disappeared

Comment: `code link test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to reach an element of `keypoint` vector which is overloading the size. For safety, you can try this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++) {
    if (good_matches.empty())
    {
        cout << "no good matches" << endl;
        break;
    }
        if((int)good_matches[i].queryIdx<keypoint02.size() && (int)good_matches[i].trainIdx<keypoint01.size)
        {
           imagePoint2.push_back(keypoint02[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
           imagePoint1.push_back(keypoint01[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
        }
}
```